# js called in head does not always load

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

I'm building a responsive website from the ground up for use as a SharePoint 2013 masterpage, using [skel.js](http://skeljs.org/) to control the grid and breakpoints. Once published, the js files (`skel.min.js`, `skel-panels.min.js`, `jquery.min.js`, `html5shiv.js`, and a simple `config.js` written by me to configure skel and skel-panels) do not reliably run every time a user hits the site, leaving the CSS frozen at whatever breakpoint the browser matched at the time. A refresh *usually* fixes the issue, but that's not an acceptable solution. So far this happens in IE, Chrome and FF (all versions that don't trigger `html5shiv`).

Does anyone have experience troubleshooting skeljs, or know of a higher-level cause for this behavior? I'm not proficient enough with JavaScript to figure this one out for myself, but even a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Update:** Caught one of the errors in IE Developer Tools (IE10). The console reports `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'match' of undefined or null reference` and points to `skel-panels.min.js` at line 25 character 484. I looked at that line and the offending statement appears to be:

```
b.attr("class").match(/(\s+|^)([0-9]+)u(\s+|$)/)&&b.data("cell-size",parseInt(RegExp.$2))};
```

Does this provide any useful insight? I think this is the most common error, but believe there are others as well. I'm continuing to try catching all of them in all browsers.

**Update 2:** As requested, here are the calls to the js files in the head. Note that these have been translated to SharePoint masterpage syntax (which it does automatically when you publish a page), but they are identical to a "standard" js reference and SharePoint does not alter how they work.

```
    <!--MS:<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/masterpage/SiteName/js/jquery.min.js">//<![CDATA[-->
    <!--ME://]]></script>-->
    <!--MS:<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/masterpage/SiteName/js/config.js">//<![CDATA[-->
    <!--ME://]]></script>-->
    <!--MS:<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/masterpage/SiteName/js/skel.min.js">//<![CDATA[-->
    <!--ME://]]></script>-->
    <!--MS:<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/masterpage/SiteName/js/skel-panels.min.js">//<![CDATA[-->
    <!--ME://]]></script>-->
```

This is how one looks before SharePoint wraps it in its own comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/masterpage/SiteName/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is another exception that it throws: `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method '_skel_panels_close'` in `skel-panels.min.js` on line 6 character 192, which is right in the middle of this statement: `c.is(":visible")?c._skel_panels_close():c._skel_panels_open()};`

Also as requested, I added `console.log(b);console.log(b.attr("class"));` before the first statement mentioned above to see what `b` is when it's failing. When it works, both instances of `b` come out to be "6u" which is a class from skel.min.js that defines the width of a section within a row. When the script fails, only the first instance of `b` is recorded and it is "undefined".

**Update 3:** Per the suggestions of multiple people I tried loading the js at the end of the page, but this broke all of the scripts. After doing some more reading I decided to re-arrange the order of the css and script links so that the css loaded first. What I've come to find out though is that modern browsers use speculative parsing, so the order shouldn't matter. I confirmed this by seeing no noticeable change in behavior when loading the page. For reference though, the scripts come first (about halfway down right after the default scripts that SharePoint calls), then the css is linked at the bottom of the `head`. I still have not found a resolution to this issue, so any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Please post more details. You should load your JavaScript as close to the end of your HTML as you can, rather than putting it in the `head`.

Comment: Use Chrome's console or Firefox's Firebug to debug it. In Chrome, load your page, and if this error you mention happens, press f12 and go to the console. You'll see all the Javascript errors that have  happened since the last load listed there. Then edit your question to include those errors, and we may be able to help further.

Comment: @aaronburrows that is very arguable and I don't think the OP's problem has to do with that. Besides, having javascript out of the head section may be seen as markup pollution if there are alernatives.

Comment: Fair point. Some more details in this question will certainly be helpful.

Comment: I will try to capture the errors in one of the browsers. IE is the main browser our company uses, would the results from the IE Dev Console be acceptable as well?

Comment: @thanby Yes, they would.

Comment: BTW: very probably, when that line is run, either you haven't included jQuery yet, or there is a logic error and `b` isn't what you'd expect. Please post the order in which scripts are included too.

Comment: add a `console.log(b)` and a `console.log(b.attr("class"))` before that line. Good bet that `b` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I did the `console.log` on both instances of `b` and found that some of the times these failures happen, `b` is undefined. I'll bet that's the problem, but how do I tell *why* it's happening? I'm used to tracing variables in c# applications in Visual Studio, but I don't know how to trace js variables in a browser, so if there's an analogous way to do it I should be able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When script tags are added to masterpage, Design Manager appends XML comments:

```
//<![CDATA[
```

and

```
//]]
```

even though contents of block  between `<script>` and `</script>` is empty.
That particular behavior causes `skel.js` to break - as `skel.js` expects to read its configuration from the contents of this script block (which is one of possible ways for configuration) as XML comments are parsed by `skel.js` and understood as invalid configuration entries.

Solution for this is pretty simple: instead of using `<script>` for referencing `skel.js` files you should use SharePoint ScriptLink:

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/<templateName>/js/skel.min.js" Defer="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/<templateName>/js/skel-panels.min.js" Defer="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/<templateName>/js/init.js" Defer="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
```

Hope this helps.

Dragan

Answer (score 0):

May not be related but worth mentioning...get you wiggle on via ASP.NET (See below '~') src="**~**/_catalogs/masterpage/SiteName/js/jquery.min.js"

Have you tried not using the minified version of the troublesome .js file? Obviously you want the minified, but something to throw out there.

Someone mentioned having your js at the end of your html document to allow the dom to load completely. Im curious to how you have your CSS files and JS being loaded. How do you have your css/js files ordered in the html dom?

Lastly, can you reproduce this issue on your local machine or does it only happen to end users after you have published?  Sounds like a DOM issue to me. While everything looks fine locally, when latency is added your DOM isn't fully loaded thus your responsive design and js aren't playing nice.

Comment: Wiggle did not make SharePoint happy, unfortunately (as in, it broke the script links all together). I just tried the full versions of all scripts, but the behavior and frequency of the failure are unchanged. Also tried linking the scripts at the bottom of the page, but this too broke them. As far as reproduction goes, the site is hosted on a server, and behaviors are consistent across all client machines.